# Fetching api data and Updating the Page's state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, redux-toolkit

This is the function i use for fetching data

```
export const findAllBugServer = createAsyncThunk(
    'get/bug',
    async (filter, thunkAPI) => {
        console.log("I was called")
        const res = await axios.get(`${URL}/`, {
            params: {}
        })
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data;
    }
)
```

And when the request is fullfiled i update my state:

```
        [findAllBugServer.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.allBugs = action.payload;
            // console.log("UUUWWWWUUUU");
        },
```

In my home page i call:

```
const {allBugs} = useSelector((store) => store.bug);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(findAllBugServer());
        handleSidenavOpenDashboardPage();
        handleSidenavOpen();
    }, [])
```

Now all of my fetched data have a field of "status" and "severity", i want to iterate over all the data and show how many of them has status of "open", "closed" etc.
How can i do this in React, i tried a certain things which involved using useState() but it threw my code in an infinite loop.
This is my useState:

```
const [counts, setCounts] = useState({
        open: 0,
        toBeTested: 0,
        inProgress: 0,
        closed: 0,
        minor: 0,
        major: 0,
        critical: 0,
        showStopper: 0
    })
```

Please tell me how can i update this counts and then display them in components like these:

```
<DashboardStateCard name={"Open"} count={counts.open} />
```

Comment: Let assume your data is fetched and to achieve the count you can update the state by mapping over the array and checking the status `if(open) setCounts({...counts , open: counts.open + 1})` something like this will work

Comment: @callmeizaz do i call this statement in useEffect or the body of my function ??

Comment: it depends if you want the count to be calculated on page render you can put it inside `useEffect` or if you want it to be calculated at function call you can add it there

Comment: Thath's where i'm facing problem when i call `dispatch(findAllBugServer());` the data is not immediately fetched and when it's fetched redux does not update the state inside useEffect()

Comment: @callmeizaz do i give you a git-hub link for the code,so you can help me out. I'm stuck on this for a day now and it's just not working out.

Comment: alright, i'll help you out

Comment: Doing `if(open) setCounts({...counts , open: counts.open + 1})` in a function call sets up an infinite loop and doing this in `useEffect` Dosen't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245751/discussion-between-jay-kumar-and-callmeizaz).

Comment: GitRepo Link: https://github.com/35C4n0r/Bug-Tracker-V3